# Help! I am lost in the woods! How do I get out?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

I am stuck in the Lost Woods, and I can't get out. I know I have to go certain directions and it has to be a warmer season each time, but I am not sure of the order of either. Is spring warmer than fall? I don't know!

How do I make my way through the woods?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda07-oracle-of-seasons-walkthrough-06.php#c6_2) article seems to offer a clear guide through the lost woods, as far as I can remember.

> The first path to take is that which leads to the L-2 Sword. Link needs to start by changing the season to Winter in the current, first screen. Head left once and change the season to Autumn, then left again and change the season to Spring. Continue left another screen and change the season to Summer, then head left one last screen. Link will reach the "grove" of the L-2 Noble Sword! When Link has full health, the Noble Sword can shoot "sword-beams" in the direction Link is facing. Walk up and touch the pedestal to grab the sword, then head right one screen.

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

[image: 4] [image: 5] [image: 6]

> The next destination is more the actual "ruins" of the Tarm region. Change the season to Winter and head left once, then to Autumn and down one. Change the season to Spring and go right one screen, then change to Summer and head up one screen. Be careful not to get close to the Armos Knights here as they will awaken and continue up two screens.

[image: 7] [image: 8] [image: 9]

[image: 10] [image: 11] [image: 12]

At the cost of sounding a little mean, I will say that this is a pretty easy thing to Google. "Oracle of Seasons lost woods guide" had this as the first hit.

Comment: Well, then you are better at Google than me. I tip my hat to you. :)